# python 2.7 script to add a column

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a input file in this format with 5 columns

input file:1.csv

```
INK137377383,3,2613,1513,899
INK133344444,3,106029,106961,12981 
INK112233343,2,1775,NA,NA 
INK22233333,3,1252,767,758
INK1223824,1,NA,NA,NA
```

conditions I am considering are

> If the column 2 value in the input file is 3 and if col4,5 and 6
>   values are less than or equal to 3000   then it should append
>   3_category to the output
>
> If the column 2 value in the input file is 3 and if col4,5 and 6
>   values are between 10000 and 15000  then it should append 3_1category
>   to the output
>
> If the column 2 value in the input file  is 2 and if col4,5 and 6
>   values are  less than or equal to 3000   then it should append
>   2_category to the output
>
> If the column 2 value in the input file is 2 and if col4,5 and 6
>   values  are between 10000 and 15000  then it should append 2_1category
>   to the output
>
> If the column 2 value in the input file  is 1 then it should append
>   1_category to the output

expected output:

```
INK137377383,3,2613,1513,899,3_category
INK133344444,3,106029,106961,12981,3_1category   
INK112233343,2,1775,NA,NA,2_category
INK22233333,3,1252,767,758,3_category
INK1223824,1,NA,NA,NA,1_category
```

This is the script i have tried on python 2.7 but not able to get the expected output

```
import csv


with open('1.csv') as k1, open('out.csv', 'w') as k2:
    reader = csv.reader(k1)
    writer = csv.writer(k2)

    headers = next(reader)
    headers.append('new_column')
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in reader:
        new_value = compute_from_row(row)
        row.append(new_value)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Consider using pandas

Comment: In what way exactly is the actual output different from the expected output? Your approach seems sensible to me. Are you sure the `compute_from_row` function is working correctly?

Comment: Wild guess: do you get a blank line between each valid line?

Comment: I don't get it: something is appended. And if it's not the correct value, then the problem lies in some unshown code of `compute_from_row`...

Comment: BTW, in Python 2 you should open .csv files in binary mode, as mentioned in the csv module docs.

Comment: @kto: There appears to be an extra column appended to the output...what output were you expecting?

Comment: What's wrong with that sample output?

Comment: ... **Again**: I am seeing a column at the end of the output that I didn't see at the input. **Exactly what output did you expect?**

Comment: Does that mean that what you've listed above under "Sample output file:" is your_expected_ output and not the _actual_ output?

Comment: And where is the function definition of `compute_from_row()`? Or haven't you actually written that function yet?

Comment: Okay, so we have the expected output... **What is the actual output?**

Comment: So the output file (`out.csv`) is empty? It doesn't even have a header?

Comment: So please show us the logic you've written that doesn't work. We can't be expected to debug code that we can't see!

Comment: The phrase "doesn't work" is **useless**.

Comment: BTW, your new input data only has 5 columns, not 6, and your opening sentence still mentions 26 columns. You should fix that up.

Comment: So, `out.csv` doesn't even have a header? I can't reproduce that. Comment out your inner-most loop and fix your code so that you can at least get a header row (with `new_column` appended) in `out.csv`.

Comment: Also, where does `compute_from_row` come from, and what does it do?

Comment: @JackManey I get the impression that the `compute_from_row` function doesn't exist yet, not even in a buggy form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given that the question you posed doesn't have enough information, I've formulated an answer that implements the rules you wrote about. Unfortunately, it's hard to validate this because the expected output you provided doesn't follow the rules (e.g. 133344444,3,106029,106961,12981,3_1category). I've also made the assumption that if an NA value is found, it should be treated as a zero integer value.

```
def compute_from_row(row):
    # Replace NA with value of 0
    row = ['0' if 'NA' in x else x for x in row]
    # Convert to integers ignoring the first column
    row[1:] = map(int, row[1:])
    numbers = row[2:5]
    # Implement the rules
    if row[1] == 3 and all(map(lambda x: x<=3000, numbers)):
      return '3_category'
    elif row[1] == 3 and all(map(lambda x: x<15000 and x>10000, numbers)):
      return '3_1category'
    elif row[1] == 2 and all(map(lambda x: x<=3000, numbers)):
      return '2_category'
    elif row[1] == 2 and all(map(lambda x: x<15000 and x>10000, numbers)):
      return '2_1category'
    elif row[1] == 1:
      return '1_category'



import csv


with open('1.csv') as k1, open('out.csv', 'w') as k2:
    reader = csv.reader(k1)
    writer = csv.writer(k2)

    headers = next(reader)
    headers.append('new_column')
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in reader:
        new_value = compute_from_row(row)
        row.append(new_value)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I can tell that you do not have the function I created in 2.py because you're calling compute_from_row(row) at line 13. If you copy the code as I've written it and run it, it should run or at least give you some new information. As of right now, it seems as though you haven't even used the code I provided.

Comment: Right, well in your test input you didn't have any values with mixed alpha and numerical characters. Naturally, you'll want to deal with that circumstance. I believe the community would be better suited to help you now that you have some code if you provided the actual input data you are using and the actual output data you are expecting and getting rather than slimming it down for SO consumption. Your questions are about specific errors so we need specific inputs and outputs to provide any useful feedback from this point on.